# I want to set undefined value to false

Tags: javascript

I have an **object** and this object is **returning** `undefined` values because it is building new values from an object with keys that didn't exist before when the old build are created.

In this case, `serial_modem: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.serial_modem` this value did't exist before.

`outDatedBuildTypeList[i]` had *no* **serial_number** key. 

I need this value because at the present day, new builds have this value and I need to set it to false when it's undefined.

This is my new build

```
for (let i = 0; i < outDatedBuildTypeList.length; i++) {
    this.buildService.isThereABuildWithTheTypeOfThisBuildAndThisBarbaraVersion(outDatedBuildTypeList[i], bbrOs.version).then(isThere => {
      if (!isThere) {
        let newBuild: IBuild = {
          type: {
             device: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.device,
             bluetooth: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.bluetooth,
             gps: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.gps,
             ethernet: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.ethernet,
             mobile: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.mobile,
             serial_modem: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.serial_modem,
             wifi: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.wifi
          },
          packages: {
            python_2: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].packages.python_2,
            docker: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].packages.docker
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It builds the new build with the new parameters taking into account the old ones.

I have no idea how to set the to false in case they are undefined.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about adding `|| false` after every value assignment?
e.g.
`device: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.device || false,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch empty values with a default value by using `||` operator and if the value is `null` or `undefined` it will go to the value set after `||`: 
`serial_modem: outDatedBuildTypeList[i].type.serial_modem || false`